# is setTimeout/clearTimeout expensive?

Tags: javascript

I have something like the following:

```
var myTimeout;
function delayStuffUntil( when ){ 
  if( myTimeout) clearTimeout( myTimeout );
  myTimeout = setTimeout( stuff, when - Date.now() );
}
```

`delayStuffUntil` is going to get called a good deal, and it's likely that it will get called with the same value of `when` several times in a row.

Is `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` expensive enough that I should bother checking the current `when` against my last value of `when` (and only change timers if different)?

I thought about doing it, but the truth is that `when` is a bit more fiddly to compare, and I figured premature optimization is the root of all evil, so I might be making work when I didn't need to.

Comment: i have no benchmarks for `setTimeout` nor `clearTimeout`, but i'd be inclined to say "no" simply because of how low-level they are in every JS animation framework.

Comment: `setTimeout(computeHugeFractal, 10);` <-- Expensive!                                                                 `setTimeout(function() { }, 10);` <--- Cheap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` by themselves aren't very expensive.

It's really the function "stuff" is what you have to worry about.

If stuff takes a long time to run then it might block the UI if it gets called too often.

Comment: `stuff` will be called the same number of times regardless.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So I just found some performance issues where I was calling clearTimeout and setTimeout on mouse move (on chrome). It seems its more expensive than you would think. No idea why.